# /users/tags should contain scores

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, reputation-audit

I am implementing some simple JavaScript/bookmarklet based apps that show some reputation info, including the score in the User's top tags (roughly based on [this previous bookmarklet of mine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/293/what-useful-bookmarklets-do-you-use/7739#7739)).

Now I *can* get a user's top tags (using the API), and I can also get the per-tag score if the user is logged in, by dynamically parsing the tag's top users page. But it costs me one AJAX request per tag and I have to download 10+k to extract a single numeric value.

It would save a lot of traffic if the tags in `<api>/users/<userid>/tags` had a `score` field. The data seems to be there, after all the `top users` pages use it, so it would just be a question of exposing the data.

Suggested structure:

```
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": {
        "description": "name of the tag",
        "values": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "suggested_buffer_size": 25
      },
      "score": {
        "description": "tag score, sum of up votes for answers on non-wiki questions",
        "values": "32-bit signed integer",
        "optional": false
      },
      "count": {
        "description": "tag count, exact meaning depends on context",
        "values": "32-bit signed integer",
        "optional": false
      },
      "restricted_to": {
        "description": "user types that can make use of this tag, lack of this field indicates it is useable by all",
        "values": "one of anonymous, unregistered, registered, or moderator",
        "optional": true
      },
      "fulfills_required": {
        "description": "indicates whether this tag is one of those that is required to be on a post",
        "values": "boolean",
        "optional": false
      },
      "user_id": {
        "description": "user associated with this tag, depends on context",
        "values": "32-bit signed integer",
        "optional": true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Tag scores didn't really exist when v1.0 was released.</s>

They'll be in the next API version, barring any great difficulties in exposing them.

Unfortunately the underlying data store has made this harder, not easier over time.  Taking this off the planned list as that's no longer accurate.

Comment: Great to know, thanks. Is there a timeline for the next API release? And is there a place where expected features for the next release are listed?

Comment: @S.P. Floyd - early next year, *very tentatively*.  Its been on my mind for awhile (clearly), but needs a big chunk of time carved out to actual be done.