# Can more vote-related data be added to the user object?

Tags: feature-request, users, voting

The only data about votes that I can currently get from the user object via the API is the user's `up_vote_count` and `down_vote_count`.

I am creating a dashboard that displays a range of stats about a Stack Overflow user’s badges (number of badges, recent badges, rarest badge, time since awarded last badge, etc.). In one of the widgets on this dashboard I am attempting to display the user’s progress towards unearned badges, and I have found that the voting-related data that is available via the API is very limited.

I would like to have access to:

- Total votes by type (question, answer)
- Total votes by time (day, week, month)
- Total score for answers in tags the user has participated in (the count of questions & answers is available from /users/{ids}/tags, but not the score)

With this data exposed, I could:

- Track the progress of badges like Suffrage (Used 30 votes in a day), Vox Populi (Used the maximum 40 votes in a day) and Electorate (Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions)
- Track the progress of tag-based badges

There seems to be some interest in getting more vote-related data exposed by the API:

- [API for user next achievement/badge requirement?](https://stackapps.com/questions/2549/api-for-user-next-achievement-badge-requirement)
- [Please add “total votes on questions” and “total votes on answers” into /user/{id} API](https://stackapps.com/questions/2227/please-add-total-votes-on-questions-and-total-votes-on-answers-into-user-i)
- [How do I get the no. of upvotes a person has received for a particular tag?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3903/how-do-i-get-the-no-of-upvotes-a-person-has-received-for-a-particular-tag)
- [/users/tags should contain scores](https://stackapps.com/questions/1834/users-tags-should-contain-scores)

...but none of these requests have been implemented so far. Are there any plans to expose more vote-related data in the near future?